# Boolean Expression Simplifying explanation

Tags: boolean-algebra

Currently have worked

xz' + x'y + (yz)' Down to z' + x'y + y'

Is this its simplest form?

METHOD:
xz' + x'y + (yz)' -> De-Morgan on (yz)'
xz' + x'y + y' + z' -> Commutative
xz' + z' + x'y + y' -> Simplifying xz'+ z'
z'(x + 1) + x'y + y' -> Boundedness x+1 = 1
z'(1) + x'y + y' -> Identity z' * 1 = z'
z' + x'y + y'

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify further by proving $x'y + y' = x' + y'$. The simplest answer should be $(xyz)'$.

Comment: How do I do that exactly? Would i have to use a truth table of sorts?

Comment: @MichaelMariani You could use a truth table, but algebra is sufficient. Use de-Morgan twice on the LHS to get $((x+y')y)'$ and remember $y'y = 0$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by using demorgans twice :\

Comment: @MichaelMariani Once from $a+b$ to $(a'b')'$ and once from $(ab)' = a' + b'$.

Comment: Does that not just put it back to where it started? Sorry I'm really confused.

Comment: @MichaelMariani Just focus on $x'y+y'$.

Comment: @MichaelMariani So you use $a=x'y$ and $b=y'$ and apply $a+b=(a'b')'$. Then expand $a' = (x'y)'$ using de Morgan again.

Comment: Don't worry i got it, Muddled something up